# Search only beginning of string in c++ using regex

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio

*Edit* I am trying to token left to right using regex a string with a list of regex strings to compare with. I decided to do this by adding carets to each regex string, and when I find a match I will make a substring after the matching regex string, and look for the next match at the beginning of that string.

I have a list of strings to convert to regex to search for inside a vectorcontainer. Here is just an example of one

```
vector<vector<string>> operators = { 
     {{",|;|//.*"}}                     //punctuation
     };
```

I then take substrings and search each one for a match at the beginning. In this case I add a caret at the beginning of each string before I add it to the regex to do that:

```
Token *find_Match(string &s, int i)
{
    string substring = s.substr(i, s.length() - i);
    string somestring
        for (string c : operators[x])
        {
            regex r = regex("^" + c);
            smatch sm;
            regex_search(substring, sm, r); // , std::regex_constants::;
            int size = sm.size();
            if (size > 0) //MATCH FOUND
            {
                  somestring = sm[0]
            } 
        }
    return somestring;
}
```

Now the problem is that for the punctuation regexes, it will only look for the comma at the beginning, and then find any other match for the rest anywhere in the string, such as `a;` will return a match for `;`. What is the best way in C++ to say that I want the beginning first match without having to search through every `|` operator to add the caret?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by making substrings? You can just match a whole string against a regex pattern..? Can you elaborate a bit further what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Ok, I added the purpose of the method. Maybe there's a better way than to use that method.

Comment: What about `^(,|;|//.*)`

Comment: I had more regex strings than just that, and I was hoping not to have to change them all in case I needed those same regexes for other matches outside of just checking the beginning of a string. This was just a single example of a list of regexes to check for.  I guess I could add a parenthesis at the beginning and the end, and have a different set of regexes if I came acrossed it. Just wondering if there was a c++ method that I must be missing out on.